# GBTC stock went way down but no signs of huge decrease?

Tags: stocks, cryptocurrency

GBTC was at about 1400 when I purchased it, and now it's at about 15$. It never showed that it decreased or a huge decrease, and no history of it at being at 1400, ever. I'm so confused, I still have all my money and it's about the same but I'm not understanding how it goes from 1400 to 15 and no decrease but no loss in money?

Answer (score 12):

There was a 91-1 stock split, meaning that you should have 91x as many shares as you did a few weeks ago.

http://markets.businessinsider.com/news/stocks/gbtc-bitcoin-investment-trust-stock-price-popping-after-91-for-1-split-2018-1-1014448868

> Shares of the Grayscale Bitcoin Investment Trust, a stock that seeks to imitate the price of bitcoin through its ownership of 0.09 BTC per share, opened up more than 8% Monday — rising as high as $19.57 — after a 91-for-1 split over the weekend made the stock more accessible to the masses.
>
> The company announced the split in January, when the stock was trading at more than $1,000.
>
> Now, shares of the investment trust are trading at a much more affordable $18. The split didn't affect the company’s market value, which remains just above $3 billion.